# Turning power towers into series

Tags: calculus, power-series

I want to evaluate $$\int x^{x^{x}}\,dx$$

I was looking to turn the integrand into something more manageable, a la the Sophomore's Dream, and I have found that there is an easy way to represent the infinite tower $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}$ but haven't figured out a method for evaluating a tower of an arbitrary height $m$ as a series.

This is worse than having a song stuck in my head.

Comment: It appears that
$$x^{(x^x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{n!}x^{n+1}\ln^n(x)\sum_{k=0}^n\left({\rm S}(n,k)\ln^{n-k}(x)\right),$$
where ${\rm S}(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series(x%5E(x%5Ex))